# Kusto query for getting cummulative count up to a given date

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have a database with a set of events with a user id and timestamp, and I am trying to write a query that will give me the count of distinct users that have triggered an event up to each day. So if we have the following data:

```
Event   | UID | Time Stamp
event 1 |  0  | 9/25/19 9:00 AM 
event 2 |  1  | 9/25/19 3:00 PM 
event 3 |  2  | 9/26/19 2:00 PM 
event 4 |  1  | 9/28/19 5:00 PM 
event 5 |  3  | 9/29/19 7:00 AM
```

Then the output should be:

```
9/25/19 : 2
9/26/19 : 3
9/27/19 : 3 (since there are no new events on the 27th)
9/28/19 : 3 (since user with UID=1 has already been counted)
9/29/19 : 4
```

I have a query which will get the number of events per day, but not the number of events of all days leading up to that day. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are several built-in user analytics plugins in Kusto/ADX: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/useranalytics

one of them, for example, is the `activity_engagement` plugin: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/activity-engagement-plugin

for example:

```
let T = datatable(Event:string, UID:int, Timestamp:datetime)
[
    'event 1', 0,  datetime(9/25/19 9:00 AM),
    'event 2', 1,  datetime(9/25/19 3:00 PM), 
    'event 3', 2,  datetime(9/26/19 2:00 PM),
    'event 4', 1,  datetime(9/28/19 5:00 PM),
    'event 5', 3,  datetime(9/29/19 7:00 AM),
]
;
let min_date_time = toscalar(T | summarize startofday(min(Timestamp)));
let max_date_time = toscalar(T | summarize startofday(max(Timestamp)));
T
| evaluate activity_engagement (UID, Timestamp, 1d, 1d + max_date_time - min_date_time)
| project Timestamp, dcount_activities_outer
```

and, if you want to "fill the gap" for Sep-27, you can do the following:

```
let T = datatable(Event:string, UID:int, Timestamp:datetime)
[
    'event 1', 0,  datetime(9/25/19 9:00 AM),
    'event 2', 1,  datetime(9/25/19 3:00 PM), 
    'event 3', 2,  datetime(9/26/19 2:00 PM),
    'event 4', 1,  datetime(9/28/19 5:00 PM),
    'event 5', 3,  datetime(9/29/19 7:00 AM),
]
;
let min_date_time = toscalar(T | summarize startofday(min(Timestamp)));
let max_date_time = toscalar(T | summarize startofday(max(Timestamp)));
range Timestamp from min_date_time to max_date_time step 1d
| join kind=leftouter (
    T
    | evaluate activity_engagement (UID, Timestamp, 1d, 1d + max_date_time - min_date_time)
    | project Timestamp, dcount_activities_outer
) on Timestamp
| order by Timestamp asc
| project Timestamp, coalesce(dcount_activities_outer, prev(dcount_activities_outer))
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks!

Would it be possible to break it up by event type for each day? For example, if we have multiple instances of each event then the output have the count of distinct users who ran event 1 on 9/25/19, event 2 on 9/25/19, ..., event 1 on 9/26/19, event 2 on 9/26/19, ... and so on?

Comment: as the doc i've linked to suggests, you can pass the optional `dimN` arguments: "dim1, dim2, ...: (optional) list of the dimensions columns that slice the activity metrics calculation."